# Can some of the weights be fixed during the training of a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, training, backpropagation, weights

Is it possible to exclude specific layers from the optimization?

For example, let's say I have an input layer, 2 hidden layers, and the output layer. I know there is a perfect solution for my problem with this setup and I already know the perfect weights between the first and the second hidden layer.

Can I have the weights between the first and the second hidden layer be fixed during the training phase?

I understand that I could just not update these specific weights after I computed the backpropagation for the entire network. But if I throw away those specific weights, will this affect the optimization of the rest of my weights?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can fix (or freeze) some of the weights during the training of a neural network. In fact, this is done in the most common form of *transfer learning* (which is described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning)). I don't know exactly how this affects learning in general. In transfer learning, this is definitely beneficial, as we are freezing the weights that are associated with the learned *general* features of objects, such as corners (where *general* here is defined intuitively), which can be useful for other tasks, so, by having them frozen, we reuse them.